# Obtaining All Cache Keys in Zend-Cache

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework3, zend-cache

Here is my cache initialization code:

```
use Zend\Cache\StorageFactory;
$cache   = StorageFactory::factory(array(
                    'adapter' => array(
                            'name'    => 'filesystem',
                            // With a namespace we can indicate the same type of items
                            // -> So we can simple use the db id as cache key
                            'options' => array(
                                    'namespace' => 'dbtable',
                                    'cache_dir' => Pluto::path('cache')
                            ),
                    ),
                    'plugins' => array(
                            // Don't throw exceptions on cache errors
                            'exception_handler' => array(
                                    'throw_exceptions' => false
                            ),
                            // We store database rows on filesystem so we need to serialize them
                            'Serializer'
                    )
            ));
```

**What Id like to know is how do I obtain all of the cache keys we have inside this cache object**

For example, executing this code now:

```
$cache->setItem('key1','foo');

$cache->setItem('key2','bar');

$cache->setItem('key3','baz');
```

And executing this code at a different area/point:

```
$cache->setItem('key4','foo2');

$cache->setItem('key5','bar2');

$cache->setItem('key6','baz2');
```

I'd like an array containing `['key1','key2','key3','key4','key5','key6']` which would come presumbly from an internal array of all the keys inside the cache object **(including ones that were not affected during this specific request)**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no method from `zend-cache` for retrieving all keys inside cache object. But if you wanna retrieve all keys, you can iterate the object. It is not `array`, but you can make it as `array` if you want.

```
$caches = $cache->getIterator();
$cacheKeys = []
foreach ($caches as $key) {
    // $key is the cache key
    $cacheKeys[] = $key;
}

print_r($cacheKeys);
```